# google drive SDK and IOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7, google-drive-api

i was working with google drive sdk on my ios 7 app , everything was working fine , until i update my xcode from xcode 5.0.2 with ios 7 sdk to xcode 5.1 with ios 7.1 sdk , and now i get this errors :

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/bluesettlesarlau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDrive-agxtlrnwyhhlgmfclyzmszawcbcn/Build/Intermediates/GTL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTLTouchStaticLib.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMOAuth2Authentication.o (No such file or directory)

 unused variable 'kOAuth2ClientIDKey'
 unused variable 'kOAuth2ClientSecretKey'
 unused variable 'kOAuth2RedirectURIKey'
 unused variable 'kOAuth2ResponseTypeKey'
 unused variable 'kRefreshFetchArgsKey'
```

any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to update google drive sdk, it works for me.
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout

```
svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Delete the unused variables from your copy of the Google library (send a bug report to the Google project so they can fix this for everyone).
2. Not recommended - Update the build settings in your project and disable this warning. Don't actually do this. This is a good warning because in many cases it means you have a bug or typo in your code that should be fixed.